# How to add an onClickListener in RecyclerView using data binding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, onclicklistener

I just started using `databinding` now I'm stuck implementing a click listener the *databinding* way in a `recyclerView`.
I have it working like this:

```
  @NonNull
    @Override
    public BookViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ItemBookCoversBinding binding = ItemBookCoversBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false);
        final BookViewHolder bookViewHolder = new BookViewHolder(binding);
        bookViewHolder.binding.bookDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.deleteCover(bookViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        bookViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.changeCover(bookViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        return bookViewHolder;
    }
```

which literally works fine but I'm not using `databinding` for the `clickListener`.
I have tried adding a variable position to my layout like this:

```
   <data>

        <variable
            name="position"
            type="int" />

        <variable
            name="listener"
            type="....interfaces.Listener" />


    </data>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/book_cover"
        coverImage="@{bookImages.storageRef}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:onClick="@{() -> listener.changeCover(position)}"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

and in the `onCreateViewHolder` in Adapter this:

```
bookViewHolder.binding.setVariable(BR.position, bookViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

or this:

```
 binding.setPosition(bookViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

The `onClick` works as expected on both cases but the `bookViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` returns `-1`,[`NO_POSITION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#NO_POSITION)

What am I missing here?
What is the best way to implement a `databinding` `onClickListener` in a `RecyclerView`?

I have already something that works, but is not the `databinding` way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because you assign variables at view creation time. At this moment your `ViewHolder`s don't have adapterPositions. I don't know how exactly they work, but whenever I tried to use it outside of click listeners, it always returned -1. They are not attached to the `RecyclerView` at this moment, so you won't get it without some asynchronous work or layoutChangeListeners and it will probably always be -1 in `onCreateViewHolder`

The solution is to take your `ViewHolder`'s position from other place. You can get this with `viewType` variable after overriding `getItemViewType(int pos)` method like that:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PlaylistViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewTypeButActuallyItIsPosition) {
        ...
        binding.setPosition(viewTypeButActuallyItIsPosition);
        ...
    }
```

**Edit**

One problem that you can face with such approach (and it seems to me you probably will) is that `ImageView`s will have wrong positions set when your `ViewHolders` have been recycled, as `onBindViewHolder` methods will be called without calling `onCreateViewHolder`, UI will be changed but the binding variable will stay the same, so the correct way would be assigning this position in `onBindViewHolder` method. This means you should keep your binding in a `ViewHolder` class and keep it public so you can access it in `onBindViewHolder`

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull YourViewHolder holder, int i) {
        ...
        holder.binding.setPosition(i);
    }
```

Comment: There is a talk from Yigit Boyar where he explains that click listeners should be attached in `onCreateViewHolder()`. Also the traditional method  `.setonclicklistener()` which is the one currently working does not return `-1`

Comment: Yes, click listeners must be always attached in ```onCreateViewHolder``` or in ```ViewHolder```'s constructor, because it is heavy operation and must be executed at view creation time. But the thing is, ```setOnClickListener``` is asynchronous callback, by the time it is called (the user clicks it) it is always attached to the adapter and ```ViewHolder``` already has its adapterPosition. But in your code snippet you try to assign it at view creation time, at this moment it is always -1. And ```onBindViewHolder``` is the only place you can have it before view is attached.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing click Listeners into adapter is boilerplate code for the developer.

- You should create interface in adapter and implement it from activity/Fragment and call it from xml file as you want to integrate with data binding.

[Here is the link to implement the click listeners best way.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8GDLOMt600&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when you do `data binding` in an adapter, you want to set the variables that will trigger the `clickListener` along with the Data Binding method you choose to populate every item.
Since it is a VARIABLE, not a method.